# How do I uncheck a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox that is always checked, but base on user input elsewhere in my form (I have a `onChange="functionName"` on a select box) I would like to uncheck it.

How do I do that?

Comment: Already answered on SO:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330209/jquery-checkbox-enable-disable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$('#mycheckbox').attr('checked', false)`

Comment: d¤#%, i went with .attr('checked', 'false') :-) ty ty both

Comment: Ehem, checkmark?  This guy is trying to get his first gold badge :)

Answer (score 21):

does it need to be done with jQuery ?
what about JavaScript please try this:

Check: `document.getElementById("ckBox").checked = true;`

UnCheck: `document.getElementById("ckBox").checked = false;`

Comment: i tried you code but it doesn't work unless i write like : `document.getElementById("ckBox").checked = true` and not like `document.getElementById("ckBox").checked = 'true'`

Answer (score 2):

plese see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)

also note that in jquery 1.6 you should use

```
$(".mycheckbox").prop("checked", true/false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check it:

```
$('input[name=foo]').attr('checked', true);
```

Uncheck it:

```
$('input[name=foo]').attr('checked', false);
```

Adjust selector accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You just needs to remove the attribute `checked` from the element.

```
$("#yourSelect").change(function () {
    $("#yourCheckBox").removeAttr("checked");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose the easiest method is to call `$('theCheckbox').click()`

You could also use `$('theCheckbox').checked = false`, or `$('theCheckbox').removeAttribute('checked')`

Comment: sorry- no. this is not correct. that selector will not work, you cannot access the `checked` property like that, nor is it conventional to call the `click()` event of the checkbox to uncheck it. Also, the correct function is `removeAttr()` Please read [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/attributes/) before posting.