# Why is it not possible to uncheck this checkbox once clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm currently trying to use the following code within a form on my website

```
<p class="formtag">Minimum Price: </p>
<input type="number" style="width: 50px; margin-right: 15px;" name="minprice" id="minprice">
<p class="formtag">Maximum Price: </p>
<input type="number" style="width: 50px; margin-right: 15px;" name="maxprice" id="maxprice">


<p class="formtag">Show Only Free Resources </p>
<input type="checkbox" id="freecheck" onchange="disableprice()" name="freecheck" value="freeonly">
```

Combined with the following JavaScript

```
function disableprice() {
    if(document.getElementById('freecheck').checked = "true") {
        document.getElementById('minprice').value = "";
        document.getElementById('minprice').disabled = "disabled";
        document.getElementById('maxprice').value = "";
        document.getElementById('maxprice').disabled = "disabled";
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById('minprice').disabled = "false";
        document.getElementById('maxprice').disabled = "false";
    }

}
```

The idea is that if the checkbox is checked, the input fields for the maximum and minimum price are disabled, otherwise they should be editable.

The issue I am having is that once the checkbox has been checked by the user, it cannot be unchecked. I'm currently struggling to work out why this is, but I'm beginning to suspect that it has something to do with my use of the code `document.getElementById('freecheck').checked = "true"`.

Can anyone please advise me on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the value "true" to checked, and then checking its value, so it always will be `true`:

```
if(document.getElementById('freecheck').checked = "true") {
```

This is an assign, it should be a comparison with 2 equal signs. Also, as stated by @DavidThomas the `checked` attribute is boolean so you should check for boolean `true` value:

```
if(document.getElementById('freecheck').checked == true) {
```

or

```
if(document.getElementById('freecheck').checked) {
```

Comment: It will never be equal to `"true"` (string) though it may be equal to `true` (Boolean).

Comment: @DavidThomas Actually, as you know, Javscript is weakly typed, so any non empty string == true

Comment: @DavidThomas: ok, i changed the last "true" for `true`.

Comment: @gontrollez, now haven't you copied from my answer ??

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById("freecheck").checked = true){

//do something

}
```

ref: [How do I uncheck a checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979005/how-do-i-uncheck-a-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

okay here is the solution you were looking for

here is your checkbox new code

```
<input type="checkbox" id="freecheck" onclick="myonclickhandler(this);" name="freecheck" value="freeonly">
```

While this is your javasript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var t = document.getElementById("freecheck");

function myonclickhandler(t) {
    if (t.checked) {
        document.getElementById('minprice').value = "";
        document.getElementById('minprice').disabled = "disabled";
        document.getElementById('maxprice').value = "";
        document.getElementById('maxprice').disabled = "disabled";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('minprice').disabled = "false";
        document.getElementById('maxprice').disabled = "false";
    }
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Do like following ,
It will work :

Change your javascript function

```
function disableprice() {
    if(document.getElementById('freecheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('minprice').value = "";
        document.getElementById('minprice').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('maxprice').value = "";
        document.getElementById('maxprice').disabled = true;
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById('minprice').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('maxprice').disabled = false;
    }

}
```

Also find working fiddle 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rsqtm6sz/)

Comment: Does this answer add something to mine? You don't explain what the problem was and the solution is the same.

Comment: can't you see the diff b/w document.getElementById('freecheck').checked and document.getElementById('freecheck').checked == 'true' ??