# Roles in Drupal ( User Module )

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I've been experimenting with Drupal 7 quite a bit and have a doubt with User Roles.

1. In the application that I am trying to create, There are 5 roles for users and there is one role ( say E ), which when chosen, the others ( A, B, C, D ) will grey out or can't be chosen.

In simple terms,

if( $role chosen == A || B || C || D ) { Options to choose other Roles are available including the Role 'E' }

if( $role chosen == E ) { Other Roles are blocked and can't be chosen }

Is there any possible way I can achieve it ?

2 . I also have another doubt about the statuses of the Roles. Can I Flag users in anyway apart from the default 'Status' ? Also, if that is not possible, is there anyway for me to create a new Status ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the point #1, you can achieve that using jQuery. You can use the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2330236/863380) to get you started.

For point #2, YES you can flag users. You can add your own filter as a field from `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` and use [Field Permissions module](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) to block users from accessing this field.

**Update:**
The steps in details:

1- Go to `http://[YOUR_SITE.COM]/admin/config/people/accounts/fields`

2- Under to `Add new field`, enter the new field name and under `Type of data to store` choose `List (text)`. Then click `Save`

3- In `Field settings` page, enter the `Allowed values list` (Speaker, Attendee, ...)

4- If [Field Permissions module](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) is enabled, you should see `Field visibility and permissions` in the bottom of the page. Choose `Custom permissions` and check the roles that can view/edit this field. Then click `Save settings`.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: Hello Muhammad .. I will try the JQuery part, but my second question was not about Roles, it was more about User Statuses. 

Say there is a meeting or an event and I want to mark the attendees or speakers with a status "Attendee" or "Speaker" .. Can I do that ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Kindly tell me if further help is needed... -Muhammad.

Comment: Hello Muhammad .. That was quite a lot and was just what I wanted .. :) Thanks for the instant response :) You saved me :) :)

Comment: Really glad it helped :). Kindly mark the answer as the correct one... -Muhammad.