# Jquery count elements on click with limit

Tags: jquery, checkbox

First, I have a set of checkbox elements, i want that every time i click on it there's a way to count how many checkboxes where active inside the form. Next, place a limit on how many checkboxes I want to check, if it reaches the limit then I want the remaining checkboxes disabled. Currently, jquery .length returns the total number of checkboxes.

btw, i'm using a custom javascript/css checkbox, but i think the idea is the same

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve the number of checked checkboxes, `.length` works but on the selector `input:checked` :

```
var nbChecked = $("input:checked").length;
```

In order to limit the number of checked boxes, you have to bind `change` event to your checkboxes and prevent click when this number is reached...

Working jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wpMzY/

Answer (score 0):

If you pasted the code you already have - we could advise further.

- To see how to check if the checkbox is checked look at : [Check checkbox checked property using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery)
- To see how to check / uncheck a checkbox : [How do I check a checkbox with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)
- For enabling and disabling look at : [JQuery - checkbox enable/disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330209/jquery-checkbox-enable-disable)

Answer (score 0):

Full code example of what Samuel has answered, along with the option to allow the user to deselect his current option and pick a different option:

```
var maxAmountChecked = 3;

$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
   if( $('input:checked').length > maxAmountChecked-1 ){
       //disable all unchecked checkboxes, keeping checked boxes available to deselect
       $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   }else{
       //if maximum amount is not reached, all checkboxes should be available
       $('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr("disabled");
   }
});
```