# jQuery check only enabled checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

My checkboxes:

```
<input disabled="disabled" class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input disabled="disabled" class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="5" /> 
<input class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="8" /> 
<input disabled="disabled" class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="10" />  
<input class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="30" />
```

My jQuery selects all the checkboxes regardless of whether they are enabled or disabled - is it possible to only check those that are enabled?

```
$('#Spec_all').on('click', function() {
    $('.Spec').attr('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: Hi @Barun - not sure it is, unless I am missing something.  I want to check 'only' the `enabled` checkboxes.

Comment: $('.Spec:checkbox:enabled:checked') should work

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `:enabled` pseudo selector:

```
$('.Spec:enabled:checked')
```

So select all elements with the class `Spec`, which are not disabled, and are checked.

**edit**

You don't want to select checked checkboxes in your selector, otherwise once they're unchecked, they won't be selected again. You can do the following:

```
$('#Spec_all').on('click', function() {
   $('.Spec:enabled').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p73wW/8/)

Answer (score 2):

Selecting the checked checkboxes is rather easy. All you need to do is define the class and use the checked selector. This results in something like this:

```
 $('.Spec:checkbox:checked:enabled')
```

cfr: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

to select only the enabled ones... add the enabled selector (http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/)

you could also use `:not(:disabled)` instead of `enabled`. There is a slight difference (explained in the enabled-selector documentation)
I've also added the "checkbox" selector in order to make sure that we're only checking checkboxes (if it could be the case that .Spec is also used for other types).

Comment: Not sure that is correct - I need to select the 'enabled' checkboxes only.

Comment: Thanks Kristof - I must be going wrong with my code: `$('.Spec:checkbox:checked:enabled').attr('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));` Whilst it doesn't check the disabled boxes, neither does it check the enabled ones :-(

Comment: `:enabled` only selects the checkboxes which are explicitly set to enabled. If this isn't the case, you should use `:not(:disabled)`

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery - checkbox enable/disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330209/jquery-checkbox-enable-disable)

this source check all checkbox :

```
$("input:checkbox").each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  if($this.is(":checked")){
       alert('enable');
  }
});
```