# how to put checkbox in disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'd like to disable the checkbox when an election is checked. 
Thank you

```
<form id="tform" method="post">
    Sélectionnez le type de la machine :<br>
    <input  type="checkbox" id="1" name="g"<?php if ($_POST['g'] == "pc") {echo  'checked="checked"';} ?> value="pc" class="checkbox"> Pc
    <input  type="checkbox" id="2" name="g"<?php if ($_POST['g'] == "wiiu") {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="wiiu" class="checkbox">Wii U
    <input  type="checkbox" id="3" name="g"<?php if ($_POST['g'] == "xbox-360") {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="xbox-360" class="checkbox">Xbox-360
    <input  type="checkbox" id="4" name="g"<?php if ($_POST['g'] == "playstation-4-ps4") {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="playstation-4-ps4" class="checkbox">Ps4
    <input  type="checkbox" id="5" name="g"<?php if ($_POST['g'] == "playstation-3-ps3") {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="playstation-3-ps3" class="checkbox">Ps3<br>
    <input  type="checkbox" id="6" name="g"<?php if ($_POST['g'] == "xbox-one") {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="xbox-one" class="checkbox">One
    <input  type="checkbox" id="7" name="g"<?php if ($_POST['g'] == "nintendo-3ds") {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="nintendo-3ds" class="checkbox">3ds
    <input  type="checkbox" id="8" name="g"<?php if ($_POST['g'] == "playstation-vita") {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="playstation-vita" class="checkbox">Vita
    <input  type="checkbox" id="9" name="g"<?php if ($_POST['g'] == "iphone-ipod") {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="iphone-ipod" class="checkbox">Iphone
    <input  type="checkbox" id="10" name="g"<?php if ($_POST['g'] == "android") {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="android" class="checkbox">Anfroïd
    </form>
```

Comment: Same like this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330209/jquery-checkbox-enable-disable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330209/jquery-checkbox-enable-disable)

Comment: @ryannghiem it's not a duplicate question because that question is specifically looking for a jquery solution

Comment: If you're asking a question about JavaScript, please post *HTML*, not the PHP script that generates that HTML.

Comment: Using a number as id is typically a bad idea.

Comment: I don't say "duplicate", I just say the question looks like that. So you should see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't want to disable but uncheck the checkbox when another is clicked, am I right?

You can either do this with an onclick handler on each input: http://jsbin.com/dunohofusi/edit

Or (and this is much easier) you change the type from "checkbox" to "radio" and the browser will do everything for you.

If you want the checkbox-look you can use css to change this back: http://jsbin.com/yodoridadu/edit

Comment: Please post your advice directly on this page.  If those jsbin links die, your answer becomes far less helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> how to put checkbox in disabled?

Simple

**HTML**

```
<input  type="checkbox" id="test" name="checkBoxName" disabled>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("checkBoxID").disabled = true;
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#checkBoxID").prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Thank but with while it's possible ?

Comment: While? If you mean with a while loop, yes why not. Just provide the proper id in the loop

Answer (score 2):

If you just want one answer to be possible, use radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" />
```