# Rails 4: How to Disable Text Field Based on Checkbox Value Using JQuery in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, simple-form

I have a check box and a text field in a form.  If the checkbox is checked, I want to disable the field (and if it's unchecked, I want it to be enabled).

I tried to write some jQuery based on the second answer for this question:
[jQuery - checkbox enable/disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330209/jquery-checkbox-enable-disable)

However, the text field is (foo_price) is disabled when the page loads even though the field is unchecked.  What am I doing wrong?

I'm using the [Simple Form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form):

```
<%= simple_form_for @foo do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :free_flag, as: :boolean %>
  <%= f.input :price  %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The form renders:

```
<form>
  <input class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="foo[free_flag]" id="foo_free_flag" />
  <input class="numeric decimal optional" type="number" step="any" value="12.99" name="foo[price]" id="foo_price" />
</form>
```

My Coffeescript:

```
enable_cb = ->
  $('#foo_price').prop 'disabled', !@checked
  return

  $ ->
    enable_cb()
    $('#foo_free_flag').click enable_cb
    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of javascript/jquery to do this, check this out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Krishna/tx5wv9zt/1/)

```
<input type = "text" class="txt1"/>
<input type="radio" class="radio1"/>

$(function(){
$(".radio1").change(function(){
alert($(".radio1").prop("checked"));
if($(".radio1").prop("checked") == true){
  $(".txt1").prop("disabled", true);
}else{
    $(".txt1").prop("disabled", false);
}
});
});
```

Comment: Hmmm.  I see it works on JS Fiddle, but for some reason this doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arise from the fact when you use `enable_cb()` on DOM load directly the property `checked` its refers to window object rather than checkbox element

I would recommend the usage of `change` event instead of `click` for checking the `checked` property. You should use `.trigger(event)` to programmatically execute the event handler.

```
enable_cb = ->
  $('#foo_price').prop 'disabled', !@checked
  return

$ ->
    $('#foo_free_flag').change enable_cb 
    .trigger('change')
    return
```

Comment: Thanks Satpal.  When I try this code, it acts the same.  The text field is disabled regardless of if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: @yellowreign, Are you loading content dynamically?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean does the form change?  I'm in Ruby on Rails Simple_Form gem to create forms.