# Enable/Disable Textbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enable text box when first radio button is checked & if second then  i want to disable textbox here is my code that is not working please help..

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" value="Y" name="IsLive" class="grey">
    YES
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" value="N" name="IsLive" class="grey">
    NO
</label>

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
    Live Date
</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" id="LiveDate" name="LiveDate" class="form-control date-picker">
</div>
```

```js
$('input:radio[name="IsLive"]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'Y') {
        // append goes here
        $("#LiveDate").show();
    } else {
        $("#LiveDate").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: use instead of  $('input:radio[name="IsLive"]') use $('.grey') for selection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery - checkbox enable/disable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330209/jquery-checkbox-enable-disable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by just setting the `disabled` property based on whether or not the value of the chosen radio is `Y`. Try this:

```
$('input:radio[name="IsLive"]').change(function() {
    $("#LiveDate").prop("disabled", this.value != 'Y');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/qoq9myvm/)

Note that I removed the `:checked` condition because it's redundant for a radio button, as to raise a new `change` event the element must be checked.

Comment: How about `this.value` ?

Comment: from your working example ,if i add  disabled="true" in LiveDate then in both case it disabled and if i don't add it then it doesn't work pls help.

Comment: @PatelJack I'm not sure what you mean? Can you add a link to an amended version of my working fiddle which shows the problem you have

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$('input:radio[name="IsLive"]').change(function() {
  var bool = $(this).val() !== 'Y';
  //$("#LiveDate").show();
  $("#LiveDate").prop("disabled", bool);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" value="Y" name="IsLive" class="grey">YES
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" value="N" name="IsLive" class="grey">NO
</label>

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
  Live Date
</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <input type="text" id="LiveDate" name="LiveDate" class="form-control date-picker">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your jquery code :

```js
$("input#LiveDate").prop('disabled', true);
$('input:radio[name="IsLive"]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'Y') {
    // append goes here
    $("input#LiveDate").prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $("input#LiveDate").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" value="Y" name="IsLive" class="grey"> YES
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" value="N" name="IsLive" class="grey"> NO
</label>

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
  Live Date
</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <input type="text" id="LiveDate" name="LiveDate" class="form-control date-picker">
</div>
```

Comment: thanx for help..but in below code in both case the text box hide..and i want to enable and disable .

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:radio[name="IsLive"]').change(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() != 'Y') {
document.getElementById("LiveDate").disabled = true; 
} 
});
```