# Can I set a checkbox to be enabled or disabled based on whether multiple checkboxes are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

So I have multiple row of check boxes like the picture below

[image]

I want to make the add,edit and delete checkbox in the same row be disabled when the most left checkbox in the same row is checked using jquery, i try using solution in here [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330209/jquery-checkbox-enable-disable), but this solution only work for 1 group of checboxes, i'm gonna have a lot of checkboxes group, i prefer using loop statement for this case, but i cant come up with any solution.

here's my html code:

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" name="aauth100" value="auth100" id="auth100" onclick ="togAuth1()">New Member + Kit Purchase</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="aaddAuth100" value="addAuth100" id="addAuth100">Add</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="aeditAuth100" value="editAuth100" id="editAuth100">Edit</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="adelAuth100" value="delAuth100" id="delAuth100">Delete</input></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" name="auth101" value="auth101" id="auth101">New Member Registration</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="addAuth101" value="addAuth101" id="addAuth101">Add</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="editAuth101" value="editAuth101" id="editAuth101">Edit</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="delAuth101" value="delAuth101" id="delAuth101">Delete</input></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" name="auth102" value="auth102" id="auth102">Member Data Maintenance</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="addAuth102" value="addAuth102" id="addAuth102">Add</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="editAuth102" value="editAuth102" id="editAuth102">Edit</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="delAuth102" value="delAuth102" id="delAuth102">Delete</input></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" name="auth103" value="auth103" id="auth103">Member Registration Listing</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="addAuth103" value="addAuth103" id="addAuth103">Add</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="editAuth103" value="editAuth103" id="editAuth103">Edit</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="delAuth103" value="delAuth103" id="delAuth103">Delete</input></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" name="auth104" value="auth104" id="auth104">Geneology Listing</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="addAuth104" value="addAuth104" id="addAuth104">Add</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="editAuth104" value="editAuth104" id="editAuth104">Edit</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="delAuth104" value="delAuth104" id="delAuth104">Delete</input></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" name="auth105" value="auth105" id="auth105">Member Rank Report</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="addAuth105" value="addAuth105" id="addAuth105">Add</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="editAuth105" value="editAuth105" id="editAuth105">Edit</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="delAuth105" value="delAuth105" id="delAuth105">Delete</input></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note you can use classes rather than `id01,id02,id03,...`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek what if i want to use costume class for css style?

Comment: @Wallflower Then its a choice. ID's are meant to be unique, so no problem if you don't repeat ID's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is to to use each row. Then from there select the first `div` and get it's input. That can be used for the change event, which then you can disable all but the first checkbox:

```
$('.row').each(function(){
  var self = this;
  $(this).find('div:first input').change(function(){
     // disables all but the first input in the div rows
     if(this.checked) $(self).find('div:gt(0) input').attr("disabled", true);
     else $(self).find('div:gt(0) input').attr("disabled", false);
  });
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23197/)

Comment: thanks its working, can u explain to me what is `'div:gt(0) input'`

Comment: @Wallflower It means to select the `div` elements with a index larger than `0`. In other words it gets all the inputs within the div's except for the first one (*being the checkbox on the left*).

Comment: i've encountered some problem, if the checkbox is already checked from the beginning, the other checkbox still not disabled

Comment: @Wallflower That's because the event only happens on `change` when the checkbox was ticked or un-ticked. To have it happen automatically at the start as well you can call the change event of the input by adding `$(this).find('div:first input').change()` on the end after defining the change event ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23243/)).

Answer (score 4):

You can assign some class to your checkbox. Then use the .each() method of jquery this way.

```
$(".someclass").each(function(){

            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
               // Disable other checkbox in row
            }
            else
            {
                //don't disable checkbox
            }
        })
```

This will loop through all the checkbox with the assigned class and you can easily separate the checkbox of left row with class.
Though you will have to find a way, how to target other checkbox at right side in the same row.

Comment: the problem is  im gonna have alot of classes if i use that

Answer (score 0):

This single line of code does the trick, in a change event:

```
$('.col-sm-5').on('change', function(){
    $(this).nextAll('.col-sm-2').children('input').prop('disabled',
         $(this).children('input').prop('checked'));
});
```

I'll break it down:

```
$('.col-sm-5').on('change', ...
```

Whenever an element with the `col-sm-5` class (or one of its children) changes...

```
$(this).nextAll('.col-sm-2') ...
```

Get all the following siblings of `this` (the element that changed) which have the class `col-sm-2` ...

```
.children('input') ...
```

Get the input elements that are children of the above...

```
.prop('disabled', ...
```

The disabled property will be set to either true or false ...

```
$(this).children('input') ...
```

Get the input box that is contained in the div with the class `col-sm-5` that just changed ...

```
.prop('checked') ...
```

Find out if it's checked or not.  So,

```
$(this).children('input').prop('checked')
```

evaluates to either true or false, and we're plugging it into this:

```
.prop('disabled', [true or false])
```

So, if the first checkbox is checked, the next three are disabled, and if it isn't, they aren't.