# How to disable unselected checkboxes when a limit is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to disable unselected checkboxes using jQuery. The goal is to disable the unselected checkboxes if the number of selected checkboxes is greater than or equal to 3.

```
 $('.myCheckBox').change(function() {
   var checkBoxLenghtStandard = $('[name="addon-2811-workshop-normal-    1[]"]:checked').filter(':checked').length;

   if (checkBoxLenghtStandard >= 3) {
     //Here I would like to disable unselected checkboxes
   }
 });
```

Comment: can you show your HTML code for a checkbox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - checkbox enable/disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330209/jquery-checkbox-enable-disable)

Comment: I am using a plugin of Wordpress...the related elements are written above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work you can use the `:not(:checked)` selector to filter the available unchecked boxes, the `prop()` to disabled them.

Note that you will also need an `else` condition to enable the checkboxes again when one is deselected.

```js
var $checkboxes = $('.myCheckBox').change(function() {
  var $checked = $checkboxes.filter(':checked'); 
  if ($checked.length >= 3) {
    $checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $checkboxes.prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="addon-2811-workshop-normal-1[]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="addon-2811-workshop-normal-1[]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="addon-2811-workshop-normal-1[]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="addon-2811-workshop-normal-1[]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="addon-2811-workshop-normal-1[]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="addon-2811-workshop-normal-1[]" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try - we set disable flag to unchecked inputs

```js
$('input').click(function() {
  checkboxesValidate();
})

function checkboxesValidate() {
 $('input:not(:checked)').attr("disabled", $('input:checked').length === 3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox'><input type='checkbox'><input type='checkbox'><input type='checkbox'><input type='checkbox'><input type='checkbox'><input type='checkbox'><input type='checkbox'>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: You should re-enable the checkboxes when one is deselected.

Comment: @Sanguinary fixed

Comment: Elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$(".myCheckBox:not(:checked)").prop('disabled', true);
```

To disable all checkboxes which are `not` `checked`.

You can then reenable your checkboxes (in an `else`) once fewer than 3 checkboxes have been selected

See example below:

```js
$('.myCheckBox').on('input', function() {
  var checkBoxLenghtStandard = $('.myCheckBox:checked').length;
  if (checkBoxLenghtStandard >= 3) {
    $(".myCheckBox:not(:checked)").prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('.myCheckBox[disabled]').prop('disabled', false)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="addon-2811-workshop-normal-1[]" />

<input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="addon-2811-workshop-normal-1[]" />

<input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="addon-2811-workshop-normal-1[]" />

<input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="addon-2811-workshop-normal-1[]" />

<input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="addon-2811-workshop-normal-1[]" />
```