# jQuery - checkbox enable/disable - with DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I would like to implement the solution of the question: [jQuery - checkbox enable/disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330209/jquery-checkbox-enable-disable/) in yii2, just reversed and combined with DB. Reversed means: I have some checkboxes and if the `irep` checkbox is checked, all the other checkboxes should be disabled, else they should be enabled. So I have swapped `$("input.irep").attr("disabled", true);` and `$("input.irep").removeAttr("disabled");`.

`irep` is stored in a db (as bool/tinyint value 1), and if I open the form, the fields that supposed to be disabled, are still going to be enabled, even if I'm adding `'disabled' => $model->irep` to it. If I remove the else it's almost OK, but unchecking doesn't re-enable the other checkboxes. Can you please point me to the right direction? Thank you.

Form:

```
$script = <<< JS

$(function() {
  enable_cb();
  $("#irep").click(enable_cb);
});

function enable_cb() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $("input.irep").attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("input.irep").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);

<?= $form->field($model, 'irep')->checkbox(['id' => 'irep']) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'intfg')->checkbox(['class' => ['irep'], 'disabled' => $model->irep]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'extfg')->checkbox(['class' => ['irep'], 'disabled' => $model->irep]) ?>
```

Comment: `check` and `un-check` a checkbox is a different thing and disabling the input is another, add your code to show what you are actually doing, you dont have to do anything for this other than setting the check boxes with the correct value by using `activeCheckboxList`

Comment: I don't want the other checkboxes to be checked or unchecked, jut to be enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.prop` instead of `.attr` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) why

Add the `disabled` attribute only if the `$model->irep` is `1` the way you are adding the attribute the value wont matter, either the attribute should be there or it should not the `1` or `0` in the value will have no effect using `disabled` only would have been same.

Then why are you calling the `enable_cb()` on the start of the script on load, you are using this function for the click event on `#irep` the check inside the function which is `this.checked` has no effect as on the page load with the standalone call to the function will have `this` pointing to the `window` object instead of the checkbox.

And avoid using `.click` and prefer `.on('click'` instead for event delegation.

your code should look like below

```
$script = <<< JS
$(function(){
    $("#irep").on('click',enable_cb);
});

function enable_cb() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(".irep").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(".irep").prop("disabled",false);
  }
}
JS;

$this->registerJs($script);

//add disabled attribute
$disabled = $model->irep ? 'disabled' : '';

<?= $form->field($model, 'irep')->checkbox(['id' => 'irep']) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'intfg')->checkbox(['class' => ['irep'], $disabled=>'']) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'extfg')->checkbox(['class' => ['irep'], $disabled =>'']) ?>
```

Comment: It happens the same: for a second `intfg` and `extfg` are disabled, but after that they are switched back to be enabled automatically.

Comment: there must be some other script attached to it i tested it in a separate view with only the above code and it works correctly, have you used the same code and no extra code from the answer. please add your complete view @user2511599

Comment: You have removed `enable_cb();` ! :) now I see. now it's working. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's working also like this: `'disabled' => $model->irep` so you don't need `$disabled = $model->irep ? 'disabled' : '';`

Comment: you **should not** do `'disabled' => $model->irep` this is logically wrong as i already explained in the answer please read the answer @user2511599